# Simplified Chinese translation for Jomsocial 2.4

Tags: joomla2.5, jomsocial

I am new to joomla and I am searching for simplified Chinese translation pack for jomsocial 2.4. There are some simplified Chinese language packs on the net but they are not compatible to the jomsocial 2.4. I am using joomla version 2.5.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one as of present. You can find the latest progress [here](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/jomsocial/language/zh_CN/) though - as the translations get done this page will get updated as well.

Also on a unrelated note you should upgrade your Joomla version to 2.5.8 as 2.5.8 contained a important security fix